# Is there an elegant way to do "not in" in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to convert a python script to Julia. I am checking to make sure I am doing this code in the most optimal way. Please see the following code:

```
julia> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> if 1 in a
           print("1 is in a")
       end
1 is in a
julia> if 6 not in a
           print("6 not in a")
       end
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Int64) used in boolean context
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1

julia> push!(a, 6)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
julia> if (6 in a) == true
           print("6 in a")
       end
6 not in a
julia> b = [1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> if (6 in b) == true
           print("6 in b")
       end
```

Am I doing this "not in" check correctly?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

julia> 6 ∉ a
true
```

The `∉` symbol can be typed in the REPL by typing `\notin` and then hitting TAB. Of course, the `∈` symbol is also available as an alternative to `in` by typing `\in` and hitting TAB:

```
julia> 6 ∈ a
false
```

Sometimes you need a vectorized version:

```
julia> x = [2, 7];

julia> x .∉ Ref(a)
2-element BitArray{1}:
 0
 1
```

The `Ref` is needed in this case so that `a` is treated as a scalar in the broadcasting operation.

If you prefer to avoid Unicode characters, you can write `!(6 in a)` instead of `6 ∉ a`.

Comment: Sometimes displaying Unicode will be a problem, depending on your setup, you can also just negate the whole expression like this: `x = [1, 2, 3]; 2 in x, !(2 in x)  # (true, false)`

Comment: There is an open issue requesting to use `!` in front of infix operators: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/25512   In that case you could write `6 !in a`. It doesn't appear to be going anywhere, though. For now, it's best to use `!(6 in a)` I think.